# Adding list to list and reading from it?

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, nested-lists

I have a problem where I need to store a List in another Class/List.

I have this class:

```
public class InformationMyTravels
{
    public string MyTravelsDate { get; set; }
    public string MyTravelsFromLocation { get; set; }
    public string MyTravelsToLocation { get; set; }
}
```

And I can populate a List and then save it to my isolated storage (AppSettings).
The problem is that when I have more than one "Overview" below, then the following code will just append the travel history.
What I need is a separation of "Overview", so that the List I populate for each Overview is saved in another Class/List, which can contain the x-number of "Overview" lists I fetch.

```
private async Task Fetch()
{
    AppSettings localStorage = new AppSettings();

    List<InformationMyTravels> mytravelsreturned = new List<InformationMyTravels>();

    // I need to separate the returned data per Overview
    foreach (Overview loaded in localStorage.OverviewSetting)
    {                    
        string mytravelsHtml = await WebRequests.LoadPageAsyncSpecificRKMyTravels(loaded.CardOverviewID);

        HtmlDocument htmlDocumentmytravels = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocumentmytravels.LoadHtml(mytravelsHtml);
        foreach (HtmlNode table in htmlDocumentmytravels.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table']"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                InformationMyTravels newTravel = new InformationMyTravels();
                newTravel.MyTravelsDate = row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText.Trim();
                newTravel.MyTravelsFromLocation = row.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText.Trim();
                newTravel.MyTravelsToLocation = row.SelectSingleNode("td[5]").InnerText.Trim();
                // Here it just appends with newTravel's
                mytravelsreturned.Add(newTravel);
            }
        }
        mytravelsreturned.Reverse();
    }
    localStorage.MyTravelsSetting = mytravelsreturned;
}
```

So how do I take "mytravelsreturned" and add this to another Class/List?
And afterwards I need to select the specific listindex from the new class and load the travels into a listbox.ItemsSource

Wanted hierarchy:

- Class/List
- - InformationMyTravels (0)
- - - MyTravelsDate(0)
- - - MyTravelsFromLocation (0)
- - - MyTravelsToLocation(0)
- - - MyTravelsDate(1)
- - - MyTravelsFromLocation (1)
- - - MyTravelsToLocation(1)
- - - etc.
- - InformationMyTravels (1)
- - - MyTravelsDate(0)
- - - MyTravelsFromLocation (0)
- - - MyTravelsToLocation(0)
- - - MyTravelsDate(1)
- - - MyTravelsFromLocation (1)
- - - MyTravelsToLocation(1)
- - - etc.

I then need to load e.g InformationMyTravels (1) into a listbox.ItemsSource

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. But did you think about `List<List<InformationMyTravels>>`?

Comment: Hi Andy. I saw the declaration you mention somewhere, and maybe it's more simple than I try to make it? Could you please elaborate your suggestion? (I am still new to C#) :-)

Comment: Hi Andy. No need for more information - your tip was exactly what I needed! Thank you! You can make an official answer and I will mark it as correct - if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the **untested** code(I am not on Windows currently). It should give you the Idea.

```
Class InformationMyTravelsList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int id{get; private set;}

    public void AddInfo(int ID, InformationMyTravels info)
    {
        this.id = ID;
        this.Add(info);
    }

}

Class Main
{
    void myLogic()
    {
        InformationMyTravels info = new InformationMyTravels();

        InformationMyTravelsList<InformationMyTravels> infoList = new InformationMyTravelsList<InformationMyTravels>();
        infoList.AddInfo(info); //add as many you want

        List<InformationMyTravelsList<InformationMyTravels>> myList = new InformationMyTravelsList<InformationMyTravels>>();
        myList.Add(infoList);

        myListBox.DataSource = myList;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Codetrix. I did not need to test your code example as I did the trick with List<List<InformationMyTravels>> local in the code. However I will have the implementation in mind for future projects, where I create the class as you describe. Thank you for your input.